# How to scan a QR code in a Windows Phone 8.1 App? (not silverlight app)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, qr-code

I want to scan a qr code in my windows phone app (8.1). I don't know how to do this; please can anyone provide a suggestion or links to me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a detailed example on how to use the `CaptureElement` to read a QR code in [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Capture-QR-code-in-Windows-f665a28d) MSDN Sample. It also provides a sample App for Windows 8.1, so you can just use this :)

Comment: wrb = await Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromStream(fileStream); it showing error in "BitmapFactory".

Comment: I am trying above link but  i got error in above comment

Comment: Please provide some more details. Which kind of error is thrown?

Comment: below error:"The type or namespace name 'BitmapFactory' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I answered this problem on the new thread you've opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771517/create-writeablebitmap-in-windows-phone-app-8-1/31772196#31772196

Comment: As the solution works now, please accept my provided answer!

Comment: Ok I will check and tell you

Comment: Have you set the necessary capabilities?

Comment: still anything is select?

Comment: whenever I am running the app camera open but didn.t scan.

Comment: are you there.. if any modifications  please tell me

Comment: When I download the sample project, unzip it, open and run it it just works... Have you tried this or have you copied some parts?

Comment: I have one doubt whenever I scan qr code it is automatically scaned or not?without clicking any button

Comment: It is automatically scanned. Open the example, run it and understand what is happening there. If you then have any more concrete questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I found one key in  that folder what is that QRCODE_SCANNER_TemporaryKey.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my working solution using the Nokia Imaging library: https://github.com/igorkulman/QRReader.WPA81

Comment: Great work @igor, I only had to add the latest Nokia Imagine SDK to the references and it worked! Thanks:)