# Create WriteableBitmap in windows phone app 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, writeablebitmap

iam creating qr code scan in windows phone app.

```
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
     wrb = await Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromStream(fileStream);                  
}
```

in the above code I am getting error in "BitmapFactory".

it shows below error:

> The type or namespace name 'BitmapFactory' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: please help me any one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `WritableBitmapEx.WinRT.dll`. It is located in the Sample Projects bin -> Debug Folder. If it is already listed in your references delete it and add it again. Then it will work!

Comment: @Rafeal Regh I didn't find Sample project bin.where it is located,please provide path.

Comment: You can find it in this folder: Capture QR code in Windows 8\C#\QRCODE_SCANNER\bin\Debug

Comment: @Rafeal regh I accepted your prevoius thread. then now please help me.where  WritableBitmapEx.WinRT.dll. file is located provide path.please

Comment: So it is the Folder you've downloaded. The navigate to the C# Folder -> QRCODE_SCANNER -> bin -> debug. There you will find the Dll.

Comment: Just comment if it didn't work, but it should. I tried it out and it works for me :)

Comment: @rafeal regh its working fine.but I am getting another error,I am run the app below error is occured."Error while initializing media capture device.Access is denied".why it is come.

Comment: @refael Regh I am run this project in my device. it shows above error.

Comment: when I am running the app  in my device but Iam getting below error "Error while initializing media capture device.Access is denied".why it come.please help me

Comment: dll working fine.but I am getting another above error

Comment: It goes to  ."Access is denied"  exeception

Comment: Please be more specific. What is throwing the exception? What is your system setup?

Comment: After adding WritableBitmapEx.WinRT.dll, i get this error 'BarcodeReader' does not contain a definition for 'PossibleFormats'. Any solution